# How do i create 3 tables with a primary key, a foreign key,unique,not null and check constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, ddl

I wanted to create 3 table and 3 foreign keys for them but I have received this error

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

My main project question is in the bottom. How not to get this error. Thanks for help.

1.Please create related three tables about a subjects (for exp. Students, Employees, Products, Books,
Club_Membership, Hobbies etc.) each of which must contain at least a primary key, a foreign
key,unique,not null and check constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    StudentID varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
    StudentName varchar2(50)NOT NULL, 
    StudentAddress varchar2(50),
    typeID varchar2(10)
    constraint pk_Student PRIMARY KEY (StudentID),
    constraint fk_types foreign key (typeID) references Types (typeID)
);

CREATE TABLE Book
(
    BookID varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
    BookName varchar2(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    ISBN number UNIQUE,
    loan_date NOT NULL,
    constraint pk_Book PRIMARY KEY (BookID),
    constraint fk_History FOREIGN KEY (loan_date) REFERENCES History (loan_date)
);         

CREATE TABLE History
(
    loan_date NUMBER NOT NULL,
    BookID varchar2(10),
    return_date NUMBER,
    constraint pk_History PRIMARY KEY (loan_date),
    constraint fk_Book    FOREIGN KEY (BookID) REFERENCES Book(BookID)
    
);
```

Comment: I'm sure you cannot have `ORA-00942` for MySQL. Please, use only one tag of DBMS you really operate on.

Comment: There's no table `Types` in your code. The first create statement should obviously fail.

Comment: BTW, ISBN is not a number, it can contain an 'X'.  BookName and ISBN might not be unique if you have to copies of the same book in the library. load_date and return_date ar e DATE, and load_date is a bad primary key for history unless only one book is loaned per day. Just saying...

Answer (score 1):

First create the tables, then create the primary keys, then create the foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE ABC ...
CREATE TABLE XYZ ...

ALTER TABLE ABC ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ABC PRIMARY KEY ...
ALTER TABLE XYZ ADD CONSTRAINT PK_XYZ PRIMARY KEY ...

ALTER TABLE ABC ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ABC FOREIGN KEY ...    
ALTER TABLE XYZ ADD CONSTRAINT FK_XYZ FOREIGN KEY ...
```